# WPF Change a label's display based upon a bound textbox contents change

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a bound textbox and I need to change its associated display label to bold upon the presence of any content. I dont want to use javascript if at all possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would javascript be involved?

Anyway, if this is really wpf, bind the FontWeight property of your label to the textbox's text property, using custom converter that converts null/empty strings to Normal font weight, and non-null/non-empty to Bold.

Comment: I had been searching and seen a similar issue which was solved with js ;)

Comment: Thanks, sounds like this will work but the textbox is already bound to a custom converter. Can I use more then one and if so how? Thanks

Comment: this wouldn't be a converter on the textbox, it would be a converter on the label.  something like <Label FontWeight="{Binding ElementName=TextBox,Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource ConvertNonEmptyTextToBoldConverter}}"/> or something like that.

Comment: Thank You John. This is what I ended up using...

//Label control:
FontWeight="{Binding Path=TextNumber, Converter={StaticResource fontWeightConverter}}"

And the converter...

Comment: class FontWeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var sourceValue = (string)value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceValue))
        {
            return System.Windows.FontWeights.Bold;
        }
        else
            return System.Windows.FontWeights.Normal;
    }
     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("ConvertBack is not supported");
    }
}